# Understanding "so as"

Tags: meaning

I read information [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/), and in other places. But I can't come up with the perfect example that move away my doubt.

I found this in [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so) which help me a little bit. But no really entirely.

**so as** to do something

In order to do something:
She had put her hair up **so as** to look older.

So, if I understood well, I think that I can use **so as** for get accomplish something. Right?

I mean, Can I ,literally, replace **so as** by **in order**?

Comment: Yes you can, but then again, it also depends on the context. And note, it's not _so as_ vs _in order_, it's **so as to** and **in order to**. **So as to** is generally used in formal English. Take a look at this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164090/difference-between-in-order-to-so-as-to-to), it might help.

Comment: Thanks! For the link to this question, I didn't find it. But I think, that have a problem. Because they said that **so as to** is the same of **to** that for me isn't. Right? 
E.g:
I like **to** fish with my father.
I like **so as** fish with my father.

It's correct that?